# Replace/shuffle word in python

Tags: python

I am using python to de-identify a word or encrypt it and then again I can re-identify or decrypt it for this purpose I tried **pycrypto** but it is not supporting my requirements.

My requirements are:

- I don't need any special symbol to replace my word.
- I want the string length to be either the length of my actual word or less 
  than that.

I don't know how can I achieve this, is there any library available or I have to write my own logic?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @JoshLee sorry for not being clear. I want to replace a word or sentence with some alpha numeric charachters or with some encryption. How can i achieve that.

Comment: Why you want the encrypted string of same length

Comment: @anandtripathi because that string i will concatenate with other parameter to create unique value as per my requirement. If it is lengthy than i'll be having problem.